# Copy values of a row in to column having same key

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to apply the below transform, by keeping `key1` as the distinguishing column.

Input data

```
key1 key2 value
1    val1    x
1    val2    y
2    val1    x
2    val2    z
3    val2    z
4    val1    x
4    val2    y
4    val2    z
```

Output

```
key1 val1 val2
1    x     y  
2    x     z
3    z     z
4    x     y
4    x     z
```

Can you suggest an alternative method to achieve the result than using `self join`?

Comment: You can pivot (from 11g, search for that keyword in the select docs); but will there always be the same two key2 values? And do you really have two values for the same key2 for key1=4? Keys (or at least combinations of keys) are usually unique. (And why does your row for 3 show val1 as z, that isn't in your data?)

Comment: There can be the all different values for all the keys.Yes I have two values for the same key2 for key1 = 4. For 3 show val1 as x for z because there is no other val1 in 4.

Comment: But are there only two possible values for key2, 'val1' and 'val2', or at least a fixed number of those? Or can they be anything? And can there be multiple values of val1 for a key1 as well - and if so what would you see if a key1 had multiple val1 *and* val2 values? (I don't understand the second sentence in your comment, that doesn't seem to relate to your data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can have multiple `val2` values for each `key1` as you've shown you need to do more work that a simple pivot. It seems odd that the keys (or combinations) are not unique, and it isn't entirely clear if you can have multiple values for *both* `key2` values, or just `val2`...

This assumes you can only have a single `val1` for each `key1`, which may not be a valid assumption but your sample data doesn't show otherwise:

```
with cte as (
  select key1, key2, value,
    row_number() over (partition by key1, key2 order by key2) as key2_rn
  from mytable
)
select distinct key1,
  max(case when key2 = 'val1' then value end) over (partition by key1) as val1,
  max(case when key2 = 'val2' then value end) over (partition by key1, key2_rn) as val2
from cte;
```

Mimicking you sample data in another CTE:

```
with mytable (key1, key2, value) as (
  select 1, 'val1', 'x' from dual
  union all select 1, 'val2', 'y' from dual
  union all select 2, 'val1', 'x' from dual
  union all select 2, 'val2', 'z' from dual
  union all select 3, 'val2', 'z' from dual
  union all select 4, 'val1', 'x' from dual
  union all select 4, 'val2', 'y' from dual
  union all select 4, 'val2', 'z' from dual
),
cte as (
  select key1, key2, value,
    row_number() over (partition by key1, key2 order by key2) as key2_rn
  from mytable
)
select distinct key1,
  max(case when key2 = 'val1' then value end) over (partition by key1) as val1,
  max(case when key2 = 'val2' then value end) over (partition by key1, key2_rn) as val2
from cte
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

gives:

```
      KEY1 VAL1 VAL2
---------- ---- ----
         1 x    y   
         2 x    z   
         3      z   
         4 x    y   
         4 x    z
```

The sample output in the question shows the `key1=3` column for `val1` as `'z'`, but your data doesn't have that. If you're defaulting it to the `val2` value then that's achievable too but makes it a even messier.

You could get the same result with an actual pivot operation (from 11g):

```
with cte as (
  select key1, key2, value,
    row_number() over (partition by key1, key2 order by key2) as key2_rn
  from mytable
)
select key1, max(val1_val) over (partition by key1) as val1, val2_val as val2
from cte
pivot (max(value) as val for (key2) in ('val1' as val1, 'val2' as val2));
```

These also assumes that there are a fixed number of `key2` values; if that is more than two then this can be extended (I was going to say easily, but it depends which keys you're allowing multiples of!). If there is not a fixed, known list and you don't know how many columns you'll end up with then you would have to use dynamic SQL, on top of the existing complications.

Answer (score 2):

```
select key1,
       max(case when key2 = 'val1' then value end) as val1
       max(case when key2 = 'val2' then value end) as val2
from MyTable
group by key1
```